# Can't access Elastic Beanstalk Configuration: A problem occurred while loading your page: Configuration validation exception: Invalid option value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-security-group, aws-config

My application is running on Elastic beanstalk AL2 with docker. It is still up and running, this issue is not user facing and only internal to AWS.

I upgraded to AL2 about 7 months ago and there were no problems. Recently I logged into to Elastic Beanstalk console to look into upgrading the platform. When I clicked on "Configuration" I get an error and redirected back to the applications list.

The error says:

```
Error
 A problem occurred while loading your page: Configuration validation exception: Invalid option value: 'awseb-e-XXXXXXXX-stack-AWSEBSecurityGroup-XXXXXXXX’ (Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration', OptionName: 'SecurityGroups'): The security group 'awseb-e-XXXXXXXX-stack-AWSEBSecurityGroup-XXXXXXXX' does not exist
```

The error before this actually referenced a launch template so when I created a version 2 of the launch template but without the errored security group (as indicated by the UI) then this error message changed to the one we see above.

I tried redeploying thinking new setting need to take effect. Didn't work. Error still present.
I tried creating a new unrelated environment from scratch, but it has the same error message when clicking on Configuration.
I tried cloning production environment but am blocked with the same error message.

[image: Error message when trying to clone environment]

I also posted this question here: https://repost.aws/questions/QU4VTSJDyCT7OtIIgPCblUPA/elastic-beanstalk-unable-to-access-environments-configuration-error-a-problem-occurred-while-loading-your-page-configuration-validation-exception

I tried the suggestions but neither worked.

Any ideas on how to fix or debug this further?

Thank you

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I'm facing the same issue, but the error message differs.